# Word for next step in homologous series

Tags: single-word-requests

When several things that are successive go in a series, they are called a homologous series i.e. In Chemistry, there is the homologous series of hydrocarbons e.g. alkanes.

I am trying to state that butane is next in the homologous series for alkanes, so it comes up something like this:

> "Butane is the next ***_*_** in the series."

What is the word that would fit in the blank?

Comment: *Alkane*, obviously. (^_^)

Comment: Hahaha! I was thinking of that when I was writing it, but that wasn't the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it!

> **homologue** (also **homolog**);
>   noun, technical
>   a homologous thing.

A search for “next homologue of” on Google links to chemistry test questions and scientific articles, showing that it's the right technical term. Also, I'm a chemist, and that's the term I use.

Comment: Do you have a word for any other series?

Answer (score 0):

"Butane is the next **member of** the series."

Answer (score 0):

You do not need another word, e.g. "Butane is the next in the series."